# postgres `insert on conflict update` multiple columns

Tags: postgresql

In this Postgres query,

```
INSERT INTO TB_PO
SELECT * FROM temporary_table
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE 
SET id = excluded.id;
```

Since both the tables tb_po and temporary_table are identical with 26+ columns, is there a way I can specify  after the `SET`, that it will set all columns of the affected row? So that I don't have to manually input each column with `SET`.
thanks

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL ?

Comment: the PGSQL version is 9.6

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid some typing by generating your statement based on the results of

```
SELECT column_name 
   FROM information_schema.columns 
   WHERE table_name = 'TB_PO';
```